# How to scrape data via scrapy python correctly from a dynamically(?) created table

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-selenium

I am currently trying to crawl the the Company Overview from alibaba.com.

For instance: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/T14-series-original-air-pro-TWS_1600273931389.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_title.4aa778f2ahtuBx&s=p

For getting the information like company name I did:

```
response.xpath("//a[@class='company-name company-name-lite-vb']/text()").extract()
```

Which works fine.

When entering "Company Overview">"Company Profile" and than trying to crawl information from the table with:

```
response.xpath("//div/div[@class='content-value']").extract()
```

I get an empty array.

resources/search_results_searchpage.yml:

```
products:
    css: 'div[data-content="productItem"]'
    multiple: true
    type: Text
    children:
        link:
            css: a.elements-title-normal 
            type: Link
```

crawler.py:

```
import scrapy
import csv
#from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest # only needed when using selenium
import os
from selectorlib import Extractor

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['http://alibaba.com/']
    link_extractor = Extractor.from_yaml_file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/search_results_searchpage.yml"))

    def start_requests(self):
        search_text="Headphones"
        url="https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText={0}&viewtype=G".format(search_text)

        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse, meta = {"search_text": search_text})


    def parse(self, response):
        data = self.link_extractor.extract(response.text, base_url=response.url)
        for product in data['products']:
            parsed_url=product["link"]

            yield scrapy.Request(parsed_url, callback=self.crawl_mainpage)
            #yield SeleniumRequest(url=parsed_url, callback=self.crawl_mainpage)
    
    def crawl_mainpage(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath("//h1[@class='module-pdp-title']/text()").extract(),
            'Year of Establishment': response.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Year Established')]/following-sibling::td/div/div/div/text()").extract()
         }
```

Anybody having an idea what I could do to populate Year of Est.?
I tried to use scrapy_selenium and configured it correctly, because I suspect that the object is generated dynamically but still no luck or I am possibly using it wrong

tun with:

```
scrapy crawl alibaba_crawler -o out.csv -t csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath selector is not correct. Try this

```
'Year of Est.': response.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Year Established')]/following-sibling::td/div/div/div/text()").extract()
```

I also note some errors in your code such as the line below which will raise an error. You may want to recheck how you extract links from the search page.

```
data = self.link_extractor.extract(response.text, base_url=response.url)
```

Edit:
The year of establishment is loaded once the company tab is clicked. You have to simulate the click using selenium or [scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright). My simple implementation using `scrapy-playwright` is as below.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import os
from selectorlib import Extractor
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['http://alibaba.com/']
    link_extractor = Extractor.from_yaml_file(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../resources/search_results_searchpage.yml"))

    def start_requests(self):
        search_text = "Headphones"
        url = "https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText={0}&viewtype=G".format(
            search_text)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={"search_text": search_text})

    def parse(self, response):
        data = self.link_extractor.extract(
            response.text, base_url=response.url)
        for product in data['products']:
            parsed_url = product["link"]

            yield scrapy.Request(parsed_url, callback=self.crawl_mainpage, meta={"playwright": True, 'playwright_page_coroutines': {
                    "click": PageCoroutine("click", selector="//span[@title='Company Profile']"),
                },})

    def crawl_mainpage(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath("//h1[@class='module-pdp-title']/text()").extract(),
            'Year of Establishment': response.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'Year Established')]/following-sibling::td/div/div/div/text()").extract()
        }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        'TWISTED_REACTOR' :"twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
    })
    process.crawl(Spider)
    process.start()
```

Below is a sample log of running the scraper using `python crawler.py`. The year `2010` is shown in the output

[image: Scrapy log]

Comment: Hello @msenior, i built in the changes you suggested and also tried around with it in the `scrapy shell` but it didn't work =/